# I'm trying to make a C server with sockets and threads that gets a text file, html, png and sends its content to the web browser

Tags: c, multithreading, http, sockets, server

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define MAX_CLIENTS 5
#define PORT 8080
#define BUFFER_SIZE 99999

char contenedor[100000];
char filename[30];
char nomfichero[255];
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
char paginaCodigo[3001];

void error(char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int leeFichero(char *filename) {
    FILE *fit = fopen(filename, "r");
    int retorno = 0;

    if (fit == NULL) {
        printf("\n[Error]\tNo es pot obrir l'arxiu %s\n", filename);
        return 1;
    } else {
        fread(paginaCodigo, sizeof(char), sizeof(paginaCodigo) - 1, fit);
        printf("Codi interior de l'arxiu (bytes:%zu)\n%s\n", strlen(paginaCodigo), paginaCodigo);
        fclose(fit);

        return 0;
    }
}

void sendResponse(int sock, char *content) {
    sprintf(contenedor, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\nContent-Length: %zu\n\n%s", strlen(content), content);

    send(sock, contenedor, strlen(contenedor), 0);
}

void getfilename(void) {
    printf("Fitxer a processar: %s\n", nomfichero);
}

void *creaMensaje(void *arg) {

    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    int sock = *((int *)arg);

    recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

    printf("Missatge rebut del socket:\n%s\n", buffer);

    // Parse the request to extract the filename

    char *token = strtok(buffer, " ");

    if (token != NULL && strcmp(token, "GET") == 0) {

        token = strtok(NULL, " ");

        if (token != NULL) {

            strcpy(nomfichero, token + 1); // Skip the leading '/'

            getfilename();

        }

    }

    if (!leeFichero(nomfichero)) {

        sendResponse(sock, paginaCodigo);

    } else {

        sprintf(contenedor, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\nContent-Type: text/html\nContent-Length: %zu\n\n<html><body><H1>404 Fitxer no trobat</H1></body></html>", strlen("<html><body><H1>404 Fitxer no trobat</H1></body></html>"));

        send(sock, contenedor, strlen(contenedor), 0);

    }

    printf("Missatge de resposta enviat:\n%s\n", contenedor);

    close(sock);

}

int main() {

    int i = 0;

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

    pthread_t t[MAX_CLIENTS];

    int sockfd, socket_new[MAX_CLIENTS], clilen;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sockfd < 0)

        error("No s'ha pogut crear el socket");

    bzero((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    int tr = 1;

    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &tr, sizeof(int)) == -1) {

        error("setsockopt");

    }

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {

        perror("Error al crear el bind");

    }

    listen(sockfd, MAX_CLIENTS);

    printf("Servidor preparat\n");

    clilen = (sizeof(cli_addr));

    while (1) {

        for (i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; i++) {

            socket_new[i] = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen);

            if (socket_new[i] < 0)

                error("Error en accept");

            pthread_create(&t[i], NULL, creaMensaje, (void *)&socket_new[i]);

        }

        for (i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; i++)

            pthread_join(t[i], NULL);

        printf("\nAteses i processades 5 peticions\n");

    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; i++) {

        close(socket_new[i]);

    }

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;

}
```

By doing some tests with the server. It reads and displays .txt and html files correctly in the web Browser. When it come to displaying any image files. It give an error.

Tried to check where the error could be, In the receive it reads the file that is given. The problem I think lies in the send function. Maybe in `nContent-Type` since in my code it reads for html\txt file.

Any suggestion on how to make this server display images ?

Comment: _"When it come to displaying any image files. It give an error"_ - Yes, you need the correct `Content-Type` for the image you're trying to serve. Also note that `fread` returns the number of characters read, but you just ignore that. You should most probably use it to null terminate `paginaCodigo`

Comment: You need to open an image file in *binary* mode, not *text* mode. Also, *do not* treat binary data as a null-teminated string.